# open viewcontroller on half screen

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I want to open a segue, but only on a half screen, the rest I want to be an ImageView, I tried searching up segue padding, but couldn't find what I was looking for, In figma, I've added an IOS extension, where I got an asset( picture below ), what I see on picture is a view opened on half screen, is there any other way beside `UIView` to achive my end result?

[image]

Comment: This feature is built into iOS 15. Otherwise you'll need a custom presentation.

Comment: Often this is called a "bottom sheet". Searching for that with Swift will yield a number of useful results.

Answer (score 1):

For half view controller we have to set height and width.

`HalfViewController.swift`

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class HalfSizePresentationController: UIPresentationController {
    override var frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView: CGRect {
        guard let bounds = containerView?.bounds else { return .zero }
        return CGRect(x: 0, y: bounds.height / 2, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height / 2)
    }
}
```

Now call `HalfViewController.swift` in view controller

```
@IBAction func addGoalButton(_ sender: Any) {
    movetoAddgaolModal()
}

func movetoAddgaolModal(){
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Stopwatch", bundle: nil)
    let pvc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TimersetViewController") as! TimersetViewController
    pvc.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
    pvc.transitioningDelegate = self
    present(pvc, animated: true)
}

func presentationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController?, source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController? {
    return HalfSizePresentationController(presentedViewController: presented, presenting: presentingViewController)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm always using this pod [FittedSheets](https://github.com/gordontucker/FittedSheets)

```
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Order", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PaymentTypeVC") as! PaymentTypeVC
        let sheetVC = Utils.createSheetController(vc: vc, sizes: [.fixed(320)])
        sheetVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
        present(sheetVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: wow, this pod has excellent customization, took it to the project. New "must have" pod for me, thanks a lot bro!